# Proper way to instantiate an object when its content gets parsed from argument

Tags: python

I'm working on a class that works with graphs. One of the ways to instantiate such a graph-object is to use a filepath as an constructor argument and the graph structure gets read/replicated from there. To do the actual parsing I use a secondary function.
Which is the correct way to actually set the graph field?
Shortened, assuming magic returns the graph structure:

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, parse):
        self.graph = self._parse_file(parse)

    def _parse_file(file_path):
        return magic(file_path)
```

or

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, parse):
        self._parse_file(parse)

    def _parse_file(file_path):
        self.graph = magic(file_path)
```

Does it even matter? It seems to me like I'm missing something.

Comment: Why do you call filename 'parse' and what prevents you from calling magic() directly without static method?

Comment: Because the argument is not only the filepath but also denotes that you actually want to parse and not instantiate the graph another way. Magic is not a function, it's just an abbreviation for what actually happens in the _parse_file which is the parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the first option for the following reasons:

1. It clearly separates responsibilities, as your `_parse_file` method does exactly one thing.  In the second option it does two things: parses the file **and** updates the instance state.
2. It is easier to test.  You can turn `_parse_file` into a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod` and test it separately without the need to create a `Graph` instance, which becomes more important when `Graph.__init__` gets bigger and more complex.
3. It protects you from unexpected usage.  Even though `_parse_file` is prefixed with an underscore, it is still not *truly* private, so someone might call `_parse_file` on an existing instance of `Graph`, which, in the second case, will modify its state, and you probably want to avoid that.

Comment: Aight, thanks. It is actually is a staticmethod already and I was still wondering whether there are advantages to #2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on OOP track, but here are some doubts:

1. `Graph.graph` is worrying.
2. testing: imagine you go about testing the progam at some point - are you willing to construct the graph, dump it to file and then read it from file and check graph from there? Or holding little static graph files as fixtures?
3. programs that mix levels of abstraction haunt you (your users or collaborators) at night and turn out very expensive as size/complexity grows. File is a file, data structure is data structure, magic() is your reader.
4. Readability? None of options are particularly to cozy to read. Think of `pd.read_csv()` - it is a nice `filename -> new data structure` conversion. pd.Dataframe is also a data structure you can construct out of lists/dict, no need to lock into a file. What makes `Graph` different?

In your next round of design review you may consider:

- a clean data class to hold your graph internals. It is probably as simple as a dict/json
- file read/file dump functions
- standalone graph transformation funcs
- staying away from classes as long as you can resist
- composing the class out of workable primitives once you opt for it.

Comment: What makes you think the graph isn't held internally as a dict/json? _parse_file is literally a file read function no? A file dump function exists too, but is not relevant here.

Comment: Even better, that confirms a guess about nature of the data structure. But with bundled file read method you are constrained about testing and mix abstractions.